# How to configure in-app messaging

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

From the following https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/in-app-message/in-app-messaging.html it is not clear to me:

1. Do we need to Provision for Push and Enable Push in order to receive in-app messages?
2. What methods need to be called from the SDK and where in order to start receiving in-app messages? Is this what we need to do https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configuresdk.html ?
3. What is the difference between MarketingCloudSDK iOS  and Cloud MobilePush SDK ?

Thank you!
Svetlana

Answer (score 1):

Your device needs to be registered with Push.  In order to receive InApp Messages, you need to set a `Contact Key`.