# In-app message not working SFMC SDk 8.0.7 android

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfdcmobilesdk-android

My app is receiving push messages but is unable to receive in-app messages. I have implemented SFMC SDK from [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html).

I have set delay registration until contactkey is set to true.Followed the salesforce demo [github project](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-Android). Inapp message are being sent from MC but my app is not receiving it.

Here is my SDK state:

```
   2023-01-23 19:59:44.390 8364-8364/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: initConfig: MarketingCloudConfig(applicationId=**********, accessToken=**********, senderId=null, marketingCloudServerUrl=https://mcywc37f654knfqm53-qhdmyt8y4.device.marketingcloudapis.com/, mid=****, analyticsEnabled=false, geofencingEnabled=false, inboxEnabled=false, piAnalyticsEnabled=false, proximityEnabled=false, markMessageReadOnInboxNotificationOpen=true, delayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet=true, useLegacyPiIdentifier=true, notificationCustomizationOptions={smallIconResId=2131165724, launchIntentProvider=com.capty.wedbox.ui.main_activity.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda7, channelIdProvider=com.capty.wedbox.ui.main_activity.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6}, proximityNotificationCustomizationOptions=null, urlHandler=com.capty.wedbox.ui.main_activity.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5@90e33ba, appPackageName=com.capty.wedbox, appVersionName=1.7.17, predictiveIntelligenceServerUrl=************)
2023-01-23 19:59:44.392 8364-8364/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: initStatus: InitializationStatus(status=SUCCESS, unrecoverableException=null, locationsError=false, playServicesStatus=-1, playServicesMessage=null, encryptionChanged=false, storageError=false, proximityError=false, messagingPermissionError=false, sslProviderEnablementError=false, initializedComponents=[BehaviorManager, LifecycleManager, RequestManager, AlarmScheduler, SyncRoute, ControlChannel, ConfigComponent, LocationManager, ProximityManager, AnalyticsManager, InboxMessageManager, NotificationManager, RegionMessageManager, PushMessageManager, RegistrationManager, InAppMessageManager, Event], isUsable=true)
2023-01-23 19:59:44.395 8364-8364/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: PushMessageManager: {
      "pushEnabled": true,
      "pushPermissionsAllowed": true,
      "debugInfo": {
        "senderId": null,
        "deviceToken": "**********************",
        "firebaseApps": [
          "FirebaseApp{name=[DEFAULT], options=FirebaseOptions{applicationId=1:****:android:****, apiKey=***********, databaseUrl=https:\/\/project-7634974512462640080.firebaseio.com, gcmSenderId=******, storageBucket=project-7634974512462640080.appspot.com, projectId=project-7634974512462640080}}"
        ],
        "c2dmReceiver": [
          {
            "name": "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver",
            "priority": 0
          }
        ],
        "instanceIdService": [],
        "messagingService": [
          {
            "name": "com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.push.MCFirebaseMessagingService",
            "priority": -1
          },
          {
            "name": "com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService",
            "priority": -500
          }
        ]
      }
    }
2023-01-23 19:59:44.398 8364-8364/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: RegistrationManager: {
      "current_registration": {
        "deviceID": "************",
        "device_Token": "***************",
        "sdk_Version": "8.0.7",
        "app_Version": "1.7.17 : 300",
        "dST": false,
        "location_Enabled": false,
        "proximity_Enabled": false,
        "platform_Version": "12",
        "push_Enabled": true,
        "timeZone": "21600",
        "subscriberKey": "**zobaer@gmail.com",
        "platform": "Android",
        "hwid": "Google sdk_gphone64_x86_64",
        "etAppId": "************",
        "locale": "en_US",
        "tags": [
          "ALL",
          "Android",
          "DEBUG"
        ],
        "attributes": [
          {
            "key": "EmailAddress",
            "value": "****obaer@gmail.com"
          },
          {
            "key": "External_ID",
            "value": "**********"
          },
          {
            "key": "First Name",
            "value": "****"
          },
          {
            "key": "Last Name",
            "value": "Zobaer"
          }
        ]
      },
      "last_sent_timestamp": "2023-01-23T13:52:29.947Z"
    }
2023-01-23 19:59:44.401 8364-8364/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: InAppMessageManager: {
      "messages": [],
      "subscriberToken": "*******",
      "custom_font_set": false,
      "status_bar_color": 0
    }
2023-01-23 19:59:44.403 8364-8364/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: InApp Messages: []
2023-01-23 19:59:44.406 8364-8364/com.capty.wedbox I/~#SdkState: InApp Events: {
      "triggers": []
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The SDK state you provided shows that no messages have been sent to this device. You need to check your audience list/data extension on the server.

```
InAppMessageManager: {
      "messages": [],
      "subscriberToken": "*******",
      "custom_font_set": false,
      "status_bar_color": 0
    }
```

Comment: I have checked the data extension on MC , Device id is okay but contactId  is null in the marketing cloud(for the same user  contactId has a value in salesforce ), https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347737/how-to-configure-in-app-messaging/347782#347782 according to this link  - In order to receive InApp Messages, you need to set a Contact Key." so how can I make sure that both in salesforce and MC contactID can be same?

Comment: Set the `contactKey` with the SDK in your application.

Comment: Thank you, By setting delay registration until contactkey is set to true and Setting the contactKey with the SDK solved my issue.

Comment: Delaying registration isn't required. Setting the contactKey is what fixed the issue. Either way, glad you're working.